# How to delete 'column index' in Geopandas Data Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I downloaded a .csv of Global CO2 emission from here: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.ATM.CO2E.KT?locations=EU

Put it into a GeoPandas DataFrame and merged it with a shapefile of the whole world.
In the .csv of emissions, the column names are all correct. However, after doing `ghg.head()`, there is a row above the original column names, with 'field_1', 'field_2' ...

I was wondering how I would go about removing that row of unwanted column names, and instead have the row below be the column names. I have attached the `ghg.head90` output below. [Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5NVK.png)

Please let me know what I can do, thanks.

Comment: How did you load it?

Comment: ghg = gpd.read_file('File path'). Got the .shp in the same way, but it doesn't have the same issue. The .csv opened in Excel doesn't have any rows above it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have downloaded same file.  Key part is to skip first three rows when you load CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd

# https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/EN.ATM.CO2E.KT?downloadformat=csv
f = Path.home().joinpath(
    "Downloads/API_EN/API_EN.ATM.CO2E.KT_DS2_en_csv_v2_3888754.csv"
)
df = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=3)
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# join data and geometry
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.merge(world, left_on="Country Code", right_on="iso_a3"))

# now generate a choropleth
gdf.loc[
    :, ["Country Name", "Country Code", "Indicator Name", "2018", "geometry"]
].explore(
    column="2018",
    vmin=gdf["2018"].quantile(0.25),
    vmax=gdf["2018"].quantile(0.9),
    height=300,
    width=500,
)
```

[image]